# COUNTIF inside INDIRECT in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count the number of letter "A" in range E6:AI6 from tab name "FINAL" in different tab name "FINAL DATA"

I basically want to look up `'FINAL'!E6:AI6`, This is what I have tried:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'FINAL'!E6:AI6" & E6 & ":A" & AI6),1)
```

but it is returning 0 always but in a particular range, there are 5 cells whose value is "A"

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'FINAL'!E6:AI6" & E6 & ":A" & AI6),1)
```

It should return 5 instead of 0 cell where I am applying above function

Answer (score 1):

If I'm' understanding your question correctly, you'd like to count the occurrence of a certain string in a certain range different sheet within the same spreadsheet in Google Sheets.

I think the following should do the job:

=COUNTIF(FINAL!E6:AI6,"A")

**EDIT:**

Including INDIRECT would work the following way.

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'FINAL'!E6:AI6"),"A")

I understand that this doesn't solve the issue you've described in the comments, but I think it addresses the question asked in the initial post.

Comment: Yes you understood correct but what is happening by applying above formula ,when that sheet is deleted and again that sheet is created with same name i am getting REF error that Unresolved sheet name to overcome this error i am trying indirect function.If there is any other solution than please help me with that solution

Comment: I assume it can be done if you write a function in Google Apps Script. You might get some inputs here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927567/google-apps-script-count-if

Comment: No this will not solve my problem.Is there any other way by which it can be resolved.I have read in this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-to-write-a-sheet-name-in-a-formula-to-avoid/894a38ee-fdeb-4b56-b943-17ed258dbcd1?db=5 which will solve the same but unable to put in function form for my problem.If you can help that will be great

Answer (score -1):

not sure which one you need but it should look something like this:

- `=INDIRECT(E6 & COUNTIF(FINAL!E6:AI6,"A") & ":A" & AI6)`
- `=INDIRECT(FINAL!E6 & COUNTIF(FINAL!E6:AI6,"A") & ":A" & FINAL!AI6)`