# How do I count cells with values in a Google Sheets column?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am able to get the number of cells in a range using .getValues().length. I am having hard time trying to figure out how many cells are not blank in a column. Lets say the entire column. Here is an example of a sheet. It has a header and I would like to count how many cells have values not including the header:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3b59rveavE9LHn4Wt8vgzGTvQ7mkbKGDKOUO_IjXG0/edit?usp=sharing

A small sample function on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) is your friend!

To count non blank cells in the entire column B:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"<>")
```

Comment: Looking for a scripting way, not via formula. Thanks for the heads up on the formula!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927567/google-apps-script-count-if ?